# $scope changes in .success() not applying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

```
    Parse.User.logIn($scope.user.username, $scope.user.password, {
        success: function (user) {
            console.log("logged in");
            $scope.User = user;
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        error: function (user, error) {
            console.log(error);
       }
    })
```

In the view, I have `{{User.attributes.username}}` that right after login shows nothing, but when someones already logged in and views the page, it works fine.

The scope doesn't change when someone just logs in. But above, I already have `$scope.User = Parse.User.current()` and that works fine. It seems to be an issue with this particular instance of changing the scope.

Comment: Does `console.log("logged in");` show?

Comment: Yes. And I added a log after `$scope.$apply();` and that also logged perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function (user) { 
  console.log("logged in");
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.User = user;
  });
},
```

Comment: @bzupnick too bad :( I'm assuming that `user` is correct when the `success` callback is triggered?

Comment: Yes it is. And to test that, I also did `$scope.User = Parse.User.current();` so even if the `user` in that functions scope (lowercase 's') wasn't correct, it would have gotten the current user anyway. That didn't work either.

Comment: @bzupnick strange. I'm afraid I have no ideas left at this point to help you out :(